# Add double quotes to 1st occurrence of = after delimiter | in a file

Tags: text-processing

Add double quotes to  1st occurrence of `=` after delimiter `|` in a file

Input:

```
Ver=7|errmsg=0=sucess,1=failue
```

I want output as

```
Ver"="7|errmsg"="0=success,1=failue
```

Only 1st occurance of `=` after delimiter `|` should be added with double quoted.

With awk we are able to achieve this,but some how i am not able make those change inplace in the file by using awk -i inplace.

Can we do it with sed or any other approach to make the changes inplace

Comment: what happened to 7?

Comment: Sorry,missed it.edited it now

Comment: seems to be changes between `ver` and `|` also, what it that?

Comment: I dnt see any change,i want to add double quotes to the  first occurance of =  after delimiter |

Comment: I see extra quotes and there was a space too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat file
Input: Ver=7|errmsg=0=sucess,1=failue
```

```
$ awk -F '|' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { sub("=", "\"=\"", $2); print }' file
Input: Ver=7|errmsg"="0=sucess,1=failue
```

This uses `awk` and treats the data as two `|`-delimited fields.  The `sub()` call replaces the first `=` in the second field with `"="`.  The modified line is then printed.

To change the `=` after *each* delimiter (in case there are more than two fields), use a loop:

```
awk -F '|' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) sub("=", "\"=\"", $i); print }' file
```

To make the changes in-place using a recent GNU `awk`:

```
awk -i inplace -F '|' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) sub("=", "\"=\"", $i); print }' file
```

With a non-GNU `awk`:

```
cp file file.tmp
awk -F '|' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) sub("=", "\"=\"", $i); print }' file.tmp >file
rm file.tmp
```

Comment: Thanks Kusalananda,it works  for the first two fields, but i have more than 20 fields seperated by |,  and number of fields count vary from row to row.

Comment: @Kiran You should mention this in the question. Currently, the question states "this is my input", and says nothing about further fields.

Comment: Above awk command is working.Thanks Kusalananda..is it possible to make these changes inplace in file with awk?similar to sed -i, i have tried gawk -i inplace ,but it is not working

Comment: @Kiran See [How to permanently change a file using awk? ("in-place" edits, as with "sed -i")](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/496179)

Comment: Some how awk -i inplace is not forking for me and thre are mutliple files in the folder . I want to replace all of them at once ..any other approach?

Comment: @Kiran Did you use `awk -i inplace '...' file1 file2 file3 etc`? Are you using GNU `awk` (on Linux, for example)?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/=/"="/1' file |sed 's/=/"="/2'
```

Comment: Thanks Emilio,it works  for the first two fields, but i have more than 20 fields seperated by |,  and number of fields count vary from row to row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GNU sed`  with the extended regex engine enabled:

```
$ sed -Ee 's/((^|[|])[^|=]*)=/\1"="/g' input.txt
```